# Qt GLWidget + Tree = crash

Tags: qt, crash, qtreeview, qglwidget

I'm a Qt newbie and I'm trying to create a Qt app with QGLWidget and some other UI controls.
It crashes after short time after start.

Below are steps to reproduce the problem.

Qt 5.0.1 on Mac.

1. Open QTCreator. Create new project based on QMainWindow class.
2. Add opengl to .pro file:

   ```
   QT       += core gui opengl
   ```
3. Create simple GLWidget class inherited from QGLWidget (it does nothing)

   ```
   #pragma once

   #include <QGLWidget>

   class GLWidget : public QGLWidget 
   {
       Q_OBJECT
   public:
       GLWidget() {};
   };
   ```
4. Do some stuff in Designer:

   - Place three vertical layouts on main window.
   - Organize them in vertical splitter.
   - Set CentralWidget layout to horizontal.
     [image: QT Creator screenshot]
   - Place in MainWindow constructor at mainwindow.cpp code which adds GLWidget to the window:

     ```
     ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(new GLWidget);
     ```
5. Run. OK!
   [image: App screenshot]
6. Drop QTreeView widget to the left layout in designer.
7. Run again... CRASH!

   ```
   0   __pthread_kill          0x7fff83e5d212  
   1   pthread_kill            0x7fff8b77caf4  
   2   abort           0x7fff8b7c0dce  
   3   qt_message_fatal    qlogging.cpp    868 0x101711a88 
   4   QMessageLogger::fatal   qlogging.cpp    356 0x1017122ae 
   5   qt_assert_x qglobal.cpp 1959    0x10170ba5a 
   6   QWidget::mapTo  qwidget.cpp 3866    0x10019dfb8 
   7   QFocusFramePrivate::updateSize  qfocusframe.cpp 95  0x1003b5785 
   8   QFocusFrame::eventFilter    qfocusframe.cpp 282 0x1003b6173 
   9   QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters  qcoreapplication.cpp    863 0x10198103c 
   10  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3390    0x10015affb 
   11  QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    3359    0x10015fb49 
   12  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    767 0x101980baf 
   13  QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  206 0x10016329f 
   14  QWidgetWindow::handleResizeEvent    qwidgetwindow.cpp   448 0x1001e1ef5 
   15  QWidgetWindow::event    qwidgetwindow.cpp   160 0x1001e0e18 
   16  QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  qapplication.cpp    3394    0x10015b025 
   17  QApplication::notify    qapplication.cpp    2825    0x10015cb3f 
   18  QCoreApplication::notifyInternal    qcoreapplication.cpp    767 0x101980baf 
   19  QCoreApplication::sendSpontaneousEvent  qcoreapplication.h  206 0x100dfc6ff 
   20  QGuiApplicationPrivate::processExposeEvent  qguiapplication.cpp 2169    0x100df8870 
   ... <More>
   ```

This is assert in QWidget::mapTo function:

```
    QPoint QWidget::mapTo(const QWidget * parent, const QPoint & pos) const
    {
        QPoint p = pos;
        if (parent) {
            const QWidget * w = this;
            while (w != parent) {
                Q_ASSERT_X(w, "QWidget::mapTo(const QWidget *parent, const QPoint &pos)",
                   "parent must be in parent hierarchy");
                p = w->mapToParent(p);
                w = w->parentWidget();
            }
        }
        return p;
    }
```

**How can I workaround this?**